# NullPointer Exception with Cookie on Android 2.2 - works fine on 2.3 and above

Tags: android, http, url, cookies, connection

-this is solved, see bottom of post-

I am trying to get a cookie from an established connection. The following code works well, but it throws me a NullPointer Exception on Android 2.2 and lower:

```
URL url = new URL("https://myloginform");
            trustAllHosts(); //because the certificate is not singed
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //Connect to login-page and send login data
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();     

            //get cookies THIS WORKS ONLY ON ANDROID 2.3 AND ABOVE
            List<String> cookies = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
            conn.disconnect();

            //connect to overview page
            url = new URL("https://mynextpage");
            trustAllHosts();
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);




            //Send cookies for identification - THIS WILL THROW A NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION
            for (String cookie : cookies) {
                conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 2)[0]);
            }





            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));

            while (!(line2.contains("</html>"))) {
                line = rd.readLine();
                line2 += line;
            }
            // wr.close();
            rd.close();
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Found the solution.
There is no "Set-Cookie" in Android 2.2, it is "set-cookie"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Android thing, it's an HTTP thing. The HTTP header for cookies is `Set-Cookie`. Perhaps Android 2.3+ is acting strangely, but there should be no modification of headers in an HTTP request/response. You should file this as a bug.

Comment: "set-cookie" does not work under Android 2.3. Is there a more general way of getting the cookies which does not depend on the exact spelling?